# Est-il vrai qu'on ne peut pas mélanger le passé simple et le passé composé ? Pourquoi Jean-Jacques Rousseau le fait alors ?

Tags: passé-composé, concordance-des-temps, passé-simple

Il est souvent dit qu'il faut choisir entre le passé simple et le passé composé dans un récit. Par exemple :

https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/melange-passe-compose-passe-simple/

"Non, il faut choisir pour votre récit entre le passé simple et le passé composé."

Pourtant, même Jean-Jacques Rousseau utilise les deux au sein d'un même paragraphe.

exemple : livre les confessions, au tout début :

https://www.ralentirtravaux.com/lettres/textes/incipit-confessions.php

"Je dirai hautement : Voilà ce que j'ai fait, ce que j'ai pensé, ce que je **fus**."

Donc est-ce que cette affirmation qu'il faut choisir entre passé simple et passé composé est correcte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette "affirmation"  n'est pas une règle de grammaire dans l'acception absolue du terme, mais plutôt un *principe* inculqué dans un contexte scolaire. Les élèves, souvent, mélangent les temps involontairement, sans faire attention.

L'exemple de Rousseau correspond bien sûr à une alternance totalement consciente et réfléchie. À travers la mise en œuvre de ce contraste, un effet de style est recherché.

Le passé composé, qui est en réalité à l'origine un "présent composé" ou "présent parfait" comme disent les anglophones, exprime le constat du résultat actuel d'actes ou de procès passés:

```
ok Zut, j'ai oublié mes clés, je ne peux pas ouvrir !
 * Zut, j'oubliai mes clés... !
```

Le passé simple, quant à lui, insiste sur l'idée d'une période lointaine, définitivement révolue, dont l'auteur a fait le deuil. C'est en effet le temps des événements historiques:

```
?? Hier, je fus malade.
ok La prise de la Bastille se produisit le 14 juillet 1789.
```

Enfin, notons que le propos de Rousseau n'est pas en substance un élément de récit, mais participe davantage d'une réflexion introspective et rétrospective, laquelle, de fait, s'ancre dans le présent de l'énonciateur.